# Add a group to one df based on values from another df

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two df's:

```
df_1 <- 
  tribble(
    ~time, ~v1, ~v2,
    -3,  213,  1,
    -2, 124,  4,
    -1,  532,  2,
    0,  423,  5,
    -3,  123, 3,
    -2,  523, 2,
    -1, 125, 5,
    0, 515, 2,
    -3, 321, 5
  )

df_2 <- 
  tribble(
    ~trial, ~v4, 
    2,  12, 
    4, 23,
    5,  34, 
    6,  53
  )
```

'Time' of df_1 has values which at different points reset to -3. All rows before the next reset belong to a group which is defined in 'Trial' column of df_2. That is, rows of df_1 between the two resets belong to a group defined in a single row of df_2. I want to use the value from df_2 and paste it into all corresponding df_1 rows. Number of resets in df_1 matches the number of rows in df_2.

My target df would look like that:

```
df_final <- 
  tribble(
    ~time, ~v1, ~v2, ~trial,
    -3,  213,  1, 2,
    -2, 124,  4, 2,
    -1,  532,  2, 2,
    0,  423,  5, 2,
    -3,  123, 3, 4,
    -2,  523, 2, 4,
    -1, 125, 5, 4,
    0, 515, 2, 4,
    -3, 321, 5, 5
  )
```

Note that the 'Trial' is not simply a enumeration: it jumps from 2 to 4 in this example. This would be easy for left/right join but there is no common key in this case. I have a general idea how to do such a thing with a for loop and if, but as my df's are huge this wouldn't be optimal. Any ideas for a more typical R solution - preferably, but not necessarily using dplyr? I was trying something with 'lag' and 'which' functions but with no showable effects really.

Comment: I get 'Error: Column `trial` is of unsupported class data.frame'. And I don't really get the cumsum usage here

Comment: Using `cumsum == -3` will provide a cumulative sum counter, starting with 1 for the first time that `time == -3`, then will continue to be 1 every row until another `time == -3` is reached; at that point, will increase to 2. This `cumsum` value can be used as the row number in `df_2`.  That allows us to extract the `trial` value - so, row 1 will extract `trial` of 2, and row 2 will extract `trial` of 4, etc...

Comment: Did you try doing this: `mutate(df_1, df_2[cumsum(time == -3), "trial"])` with your test data posted? It worked for me.

Comment: Now I get the logics, thanks. But I get a similar error even when copy paste: 'Error: Column `df_2[cumsum(time = -3), "trial"]` is of unsupported class data.frame', also after restarting session. Can it be some problem with my packages?

Comment: What do you get if you try this? `df_2[cumsum(df_1$time == -3), "trial", drop = TRUE]`? Do you get a vector of 2 2 2 2 4 4 4 4 5? The error sounds like the result of subsetting is a data frame and not a vector.

Comment: Yay, adding 'drop' argument worked!

Comment: Great - glad to hear - with `drop` it will ensure you are returned a vector and not a data frame.